# How to remove single quote in C#'s SQL query string?

Tags: c#, sql

In C#.net, I'm trying to pass the radiobutton's selected value into SQL's SELECT statement. This string is a part of my code that can export my values to Excel.

```
string whitespace_1 = " ";

strQuery1 += " SELECT TOP 1 ";
strQuery1 += "'" + RadioButtonList_ReportOption.SelectedValue + "'";
strQuery1 += "'" + whitespace_1 + "'";
strQuery1 += "'" + RadioButtonList_ReportType.SelectedValue + "'";
strQuery1 += "AS [Item Movement Report]";
```

How do I properly get rid of the single quotes between the Items and Summary?
Thanks

current:

[image]

Want to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `strQuery1` in the debugger, and you'll see the doubled up `'` characters which mean `'` in the data.

Comment: Remove the single quotes from line 5

Comment: This code is textbook sql injection btw. Don't write code like this in production, or actually, don't write it ever. Use SqlParameters instead with a SqlCommand in C# to avoid this.

Comment: @CharlieBrown, you've told him what not to do.  How about telling him what he should do instead?

Comment: @DanBracuk Your right. Updated my comment.

Comment: Please clarify your question: currently it looks like you are asking for explanation of "Why using string concatenation when building SQL queries is bad", but I may be wrong. If it is indeed your question - check out [bobby tables (aka "Exploits of Mom")](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: This is also a textbook example of "how not to build a string"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check what the final string will be?  Because it will be this: `select top 1 'All Items'' ''Summary' as [Item Movement Report]`.  The MS SQL escape string for a character tick is a double tick.

Remove the double tick from your select statement and it should work as you want.

```
string whitespace_1 = " ";

strQuery1 += " SELECT TOP 1 ";
strQuery1 += "'" + RadioButtonList_ReportOption.SelectedValue;
strQuery1 += whitespace_1;
strQuery1 += RadioButtonList_ReportType.SelectedValue + "'";
strQuery1 += "AS [Item Movement Report]";
```

Comment: -1: Sample of SQL injection is not a good answer for non-security related question (possibly acceptable as negative sample).

Comment: The user is not asking anything about security related issues.  Granted, the code isn't very secure; but that's a different scope entirely.

Comment: @Snow I'm not sure what you're after. You're building a string - you can control how many spaces you want or not simply by adding them in where it is needed.

Comment: for this case i can only control one space, not multiple spaces.

Comment: Why, exactly, can't you add another space?  Even this: `string whitespace_1 = "  ";` would add a second space that you wanted...

Answer (score -1):

Add spaces between the `'` in the string.

```
strQuery1 += " SELECT TOP 1 ";
strQuery1 += "'" + RadioButtonList_ReportOption.SelectedValue + "' ";
strQuery1 += "'" + whitespace_1 + "' ";
strQuery1 += "'" + RadioButtonList_ReportType.SelectedValue + "'";
strQuery1 += "AS [Item Movement Report]";
```

Comment: -1: Sample of SQL injection is not a good answer for non-security related question (possibly acceptable as negative sample). Note that `SelectedValue` is string coming directly from user.

Answer (score -1):

change
strQuery1 += **"'"** + whitespace_1 + **"'"**;
to
strQuery1 += whitespace_1;

Essentially just removing the ' you have in place